# Undo/Compensate service call in for-comprehension

Tags: scala

I have a couple of service call to make (1 GET and 5 POSTs). If the 1 POST works and a problem occurs with any of the next I want to compensate/rollback/undo the first POST

So in the following, I would need to call `deleteFoo` if `insertFoo` was successful but any problem occurred in `insertChild1` to  `insertChild4`

```
for {
    barName <- barName()
    f <- insertFoo(barName)
    _ <- insertChild1(f.id) if f.id.isDefined
    _ <- insertChild2(f.id) if f.id.isDefined
    _ <- insertChild3(f.id) if f.id.isDefined
    _ <- insertChild4(f.id) if f.id.isDefined
} yield f
```

I have been trying to break it up in two for comprehensions but it every time I end up with messy and smelly code (but after an edit it works now, however i am not happy with the style)

```
// this code looks awful, and does not work
val r1 = for {
    barName <- barName()
    f <- insertFoo(barName)
} yield e

r1.flatMap { f =>
    f.id match {
        case Some(id) => 
            val r2 = for {
                _ <- insertChild1(id)
                _ <- insertChild2(id)
                _ <- insertChild3(id)
                _ <- insertChild4(id)
            } yield Unit
            r2 transform {
                case Failure(e) =>
                    // The compensation
                    deleteFoo(id)
                    Failure(e)
                case Success(v) => Success(e)
            }
    }

}

r1
```

p.s. perhaps there is something in cats (we are using cats already here and there)

Comment: I could hazard a guess, but I need to ask: what are the types of `barName`, `insertFoo`, `insertChild`, etc.? Edit your question and add that piece of information there.

Comment: `barName` could be anything, `insertFoo` returns some type with an `Option(id)` and `insertChildx` are all `Future[Unit]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type to represent the result of the operation. The following for-comprehension will yield a `Future[Either[Exception, Foo]]`, which will be one of the following:

- a failed future if inserting `foo` failed
- a successful `Future[Left[Exception]]`, which in turn will contain the exception that caused the failure inserting children

  - This case will also handle deleting `foo`
- a successful `Future[Right[Foo]]`

---

```
for {
  barName <- barName()
  f <- insertFoo(barName) if f.id.isDefined
  res <- insertChildren(f).recoverWith(cleanUpFoo(f.id))
} yield res

private def insertChildren(f: Foo): Future[Either[Exception, Foo]] =
  for {
    _ <- insertChild1(f.id)
    _ <- insertChild2(f.id)
    _ <- insertChild3(f.id)
    _ <- insertChild4(f.id)
  } yield Right(f)

private def cleanUpFoo(id: Int)(e: Exception): Future[Either[Exception, Foo]] =
  deleteFoo(id).map(_ => Left(e))
```

Comment: Looks much better, but i would loose the information on the exception occurring in one of the `insertChild` calls.

Comment: @jen I don't think you would, in fact, that's exactly the exception you would get in `Future[Left[Exception]]`